# Importing existing terraform resources using a tag or pattern

Tags: terraform

Due to some accident my `.tfstate` got deleted and current situation is I have all the resources up and live and also have all the terraform code for those resources. However, whats not there is the state.

I am aware of `terraform import` but reading documentation what I understood that you have to individually specify resource names to import it. This will be too tedious or impractical since the number of resources are high.The backend being used it `azurerm`.

My questions is, is there a way I can import existing resource using a filter such as  tags or name pattern?

I am aware of third party tools such as `terraformer` but I am looking for a more standard and fool proof way to do it, since the infrastructure is of critical nature.

Comment: Maybe you can give `terraform refresh` (https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/refresh) a try, but it won't do magic I'm afraid.
Also, some resources don't even support `terraform import` so you'll have to recreate all those

Comment: @whites11 refresh won't do anything here to help. It will only refresh things that are already in the state file.

Comment: There is currently no way to do what you are asking. This is why it is so important to use a backend for the state file that makes it very difficult to delete the state file.

Answer (score 0):

[Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) is a tool that supports large scale import jobs by pattern. It explicitly supports most major and minor cloud providers, including azure.

Comment: Yes, aware of tools such as `terraformer` but I am looking for a more standard and fool proof way to do it, since the infrastructure is of critical nature